# Consulta MySQL ¿Cuantos hijos tiene Berenice?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql

**Esta es la Base de datos y lo que quiero saber es como hacer la consulta de cuantos hijos tiene Berenice**

```
create database padres_hijos;
use padres_hijos;

create table padres(padre_id varchar (20) primary key,
nombres varchar(30), apellidos varchar (30))engine=innodb;

create table hijos(
hijo_id varchar (20) primary key,
nombres varchar(30),
edad int(30),
padre_id varchar(20),
foreign key (padre_id) references padres (padre_id)
on update cascade on delete cascade)engine=innodb;

insert into padres values("L-001","Luis","Barrientos Lópéz");
insert into padres values("B-002","Berenice","Cerezo Moreno");
insert into padres values("C-003","Cesar","Centeno Núñes");
insert into padres values("P-004","Paty","Juárez Fenández");

insert into hijos values("G-001","Guillermo",18,"P-004");
insert into hijos values("H-002","Humberto",25,"C-003");
insert into hijos values("K-003","Karen",14,"B-002");
insert into hijos values("R-004","Rosita",20,"B-002");    
insert into hijos values("X-005","Xiomara",10,"L-001");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que te debe quedar de este modo

**CONSULTA**

```
SELECT padres.nombres, COUNT(hijos.nombres) as Total
FROM padres
JOIN hijos
ON padres.padre_id = hijos.padre_id
WHERE padres.nombres = 'Berenice';
```

**RESULTADO**

```
+----------+-------+
| nombres  | Total |
+----------+-------+
| Berenice |     2 |
+----------+-------+
```

**LO QUE HICE**

1. hacer un `COUNT()` sobre la columna de los nombres en la tabla hijos
2. Hice un `JOIN` con la tabla hijos
3. Busque aquellos registros que fueran iguales por medio de la llave primaria `padre_id` en la tabla padres, con la llave foránea `padre_id` en la tabla hijos
4. Por último con un `where` al final le indique que solo haga el conteo donde el nombre del padre seal igual a berenice

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si deseas por ejemplo que te muestre la cantidad de hijos pero por cada padre, basta que uses la sentencia `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT padres.nombres, COUNT(hijos.nombres) as Total
FROM padres
JOIN hijos
ON padres.padre_id = hijos.padre_id
GROUP BY padres.nombres;
+----------+-------+
| nombres  | Total |
+----------+-------+
| Berenice |     2 |
| Cesar    |     1 |
| Luis     |     1 |
| Paty     |     1 |
+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres saber la cantida lo haces cin un count()

```
 select count(h.hijo_id) from hijos h
 inner join padres p on (p.padre_id = h.hijo_id)
 where p.nombres = 'Berenice'
```